# How do I solve EncryptedStorage error when I make a https request?

Tags: codenameone

I try to encrypt my secure data with EncryptedStorage described in [EncryptedStorage](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/seamless-storage-encryption.html#)

I add the code below
EncryptedStorage.install("weejgrieqjgewgjwerrgjerwgmwe 9");

It shows error messages when my program makes a https request.

```
org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: last block incomplete in decryption
```

[Network Thread] 0:0:0,2 - Exception: org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException - last block incomplete in decryption
[Network Thread] 0:0:0,648 - Exception: org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException - last block incomplete in decryption
[Network Thread] 0:0:0,749 - Exception: org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException - last block incomplete in decryption
[Network Thread] 0:0:1,252 - Exception: org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException - last block incomplete in decryption
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.java:281)
at com.codename1.crypto.EncryptedStorage.createInputStream(EncryptedStorage.java:63)
at com.codename1.io.Storage.readObject(Storage.java:265)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.getCookiesForURL(CodenameOneImplementation.java:4700)
at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperationComplete(ConnectionRequest.java:830)
at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:341)

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The cookies file isn't encrypted. I'm assuming it was written before you applied the encryption everything.

So just before applying the encryption delete the cookies file:

```
deleteStorageFile("Cookies");
```